# How to handle exceptions while unit testing using JUnit?

Tags: java, exception, junit

If a method throwing an exception, how to write a test case to verify that method is actually throwing the expected exception?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785618/in-java-how-can-i-validate-a-thrown-exception-with-junit?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and catch the desired exception and do something like `assertTrue(true)`:

```
@Test
testIfThrowsException(){
    try{
        funcThatShouldThrowException(arg1, agr2, agr3);
        assertTrue("Exception wasn't thrown", false);
    }
    catch(DesiredException de){
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Can you elaborate?

Comment: If you go down this path use "fail" and don't include anything in the catch statement.

Answer (score 12):

In newest versions of JUnit it works that way:

```
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;

public class NumberFormatterExceptionsTests {

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void shouldThrowExceptionWhenDecimalDigitsNumberIsBelowZero() {
        thrown.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class); // you declare specific exception here
        NumberFormatter.formatDoubleUsingStringBuilder(6.9, -1);
    }
}
```

more on ExpectedExceptions:

http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html

http://alexruiz.developerblogs.com/?p=1530

```
// These tests all pass.
 public static class HasExpectedException {
        @Rule
        public ExpectedException thrown= ExpectedException.none();

        @Test
        public void throwsNothing() {
    // no exception expected, none thrown: passes.
        }

        @Test
        public void throwsNullPointerException() {
                thrown.expect(NullPointerException.class);
                throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        @Test
        public void throwsNullPointerExceptionWithMessage() {
                thrown.expect(NullPointerException.class);
                thrown.expectMessage("happened?");
                thrown.expectMessage(startsWith("What"));
                throw new NullPointerException("What happened?");
        }
 }
```

Comment: I havent seen this before. thanks for sharing. Does this have any advantage over doing @Test(expected...). I'll have to look this up later tonight

Comment: @RNJ, I have seen it first time few days ago. But it works smoothly, just the way someone would expect.

Comment: that's my evening sorted then ;)

Comment: @Dantuch that is useful answer. Could you please put your valuable comments on gfgqtmakia answer, accepted for earlier versions of Junit.

Answer (score 5):

Two options that I know of.

If using junit4

```
@Test(expected = Exception.class)
```

or if using junit3

```
try {
    methodThatThrows();
    fail("this method should throw excpetion Exception");
catch (Exception expect){}
```

Both of these catch Exception. I would recommend catching the exception you are looking for rather than a generic one.

Comment: +1 for the JUnit 4 approach.  It's by far the most common I've seen, and quite well self-documenting.