# JAVA: JUnitTest, testing method that throws two exceptions

Tags: java, exception, junit, junit4

I'm testing a method that throws two different exceptions.  This is my header:

`@Test (expected = A8InvalidInputException.class)`

`public void testGuessCharacter() throws A8InvalidInputException, A8AlreadyGuessedException
{
...
}`

The body has two try/catch blocks (a search on SO resulted in a post that said that's how you test that exceptions are thrown), one for each exception.  It seems to me I should break this up into two test methods, especially because I can only have one *expected* attribute.  However, when I do that, the method that is supposed to be testing A8InvalidInputException is requiring a try/catch for A8AlreadyGuessedException, and the method that is supposed to be testing A8AlreadyGuessedException is requiring a try/catch for A8InvalidInputException. I'm not really sure how to write this test.  This is the method I'm trying to test:

```
/**
 * This method returns whether a specified character exists in the keyPhrase field
 * @param guess  a character being checked for in the keyPhrase field
 * @return  returns whether a specified character exists in the keyPhrase field
 * @throws A8InvalidInputException  if a non-valid character is passed as input to this method
 * @throws A8AlreadyGuessedException  if a valid character which has already been guessed is passed as input to this method
 */
public boolean guessCharacter(char guess) throws A8InvalidInputException, A8AlreadyGuessedException
{
    if(isValidCharacter(guess))
    {
        guess = Character.toLowerCase(guess);

        if(guessedCharacters.contains(guess) )
        {
            throw new A8AlreadyGuessedException("" + guess);
        }
        else
        {
            guessedCharacters.add(guess);
            if(keyPhrase.contains("" + guess))
                return true;
            else
            {
                numberOfGuessesLeft--;
                return false;
            }
        }       
    }
    else
    {
        throw new A8InvalidInputException("" + guess);
    }
}
```

Comment: The method is too long anyway.

Comment: Dave, my instructor provided it.  I didn't write it.  Aside from that, I thought 30 lines was the industry accepted max according to the Java coding guidelines/style guide.

Comment: "Industry-accepted max?" Never heard of such a thing. More importantly, it has a high-enough cyclomatic complexity to make me twitchy: the conditionals are too deeply-nested to allow convenient reasoning, and there's nested where none is required. Duplicated logic because there's a char when everything else expects a string.  Simple flattening (roughly https://gist.github.com/davelnewton/258761cbf3143da4288c) solves that problem. Proper refactoring makes testing so trivial as to be almost funny.

Comment: Well, the testing is for practice, so it's not complex at all.  I had another instructor who taught us to validate input BEFORE passing it as an argument.  It gets confusing.

Comment: Where data validation occurs is largely immaterial. But you're incorrect; the method is at the upper limit of cyclomatic complexity (10 is a typical default max; I get twitchy around ~5). Methods should do one thing, and do it completely. This method does significantly more than one thing, increasing cognitive load without a corresponding benefit. And it's harder to test as a result.

Comment: Well, again, it's not me.  There is a style guide in my text book that says 30 lines.  I don't like overly complex methods either, so I agree with you.

Comment: Don't confuse lines with more meaningful statistics or obvious things like "shape": a long method with low CC is easier to reason about than a short method with high CC. A flat method with the same CC as a nested method (e.g., first example in the gist) is easier to reason about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A method can throw only one exception when it is ran. That’s why there can be only one expected attributed.

You may want to have three test cases: one when the method throws one exception, one when the method throws the other, and one when the method doesn’t throw any exception at all.

Do not put any try/catch statement in your `@Test` methods, just declare that they throw exceptions.

Comment: Etienne, okay this makes sense, but what do you mean just declare they throw exceptions?  I'm just learning about JUnitTesting this week, so this isn't quite intuitive for me just yet.  Thanks.

Comment: I meant put `throws A8InvalidInputException, A8AlreadyGuessedException` in the test method header, but I now see you did it. So why do you need try/catch blocks in the body?

Comment: I saw a [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785618/in-java-how-can-i-validate-a-thrown-exception-with-junit) on SO that said try/catch blocks were the way to accomplish this.  Otherwise, I'm not really sure how to write the test.

Comment: The post you are linking is about a more complex situation. In your case, you don’t need (and shouldn’t have) a try/catch block in your test method.

Comment: Okay, well can you give me a clue as to what the body should look like based on what I submitted above?

Comment: Your body should contain one or several calls to the method you want to test. In order to test for the A8AlreadyGuessedException you will typically call it twice with the same input character.

Comment: Oh, that's it?!  Okay, I did that.  I just thought there was more to it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Just add both exceptions in the throws clause:

```
@Test (expected = A8InvalidCharacterException.class) 
public void testInvalidCharacterScenario() throws A8InvalidInputException, A8AlreadyGuessedException { ... }

@Test (expected = A8InvalidInputException.class) 
public void testInvalidInputScenario() throws A8InvalidInputException, A8AlreadyGuessedException { ... }
```

Then, if one test throws the other exception (the unexpected one) then your test will automatically fail.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should break this up into two unit tests. One with an invalid input to trigger the `A8InvalidInputException` and another with an "already guessed" input to trigger the `A8AlreadyGuessedException`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider, to make writing your tests a little simpler, breaking them out into two distinct portions - testing `isValidCharacter` and testing `guessCharacter` separately.

Presuming that `isValidCharacter(guess)` will fail if you receive an invalid guess, I think that throwing `A8InvalidInputException` in that method would be ideal.

```
public boolean isValidCharacter(char guess) throws A8InvalidInputException {
    // have your logic to check the guess, and if it's invalid, throw
}
```

Then all you would need to do is test *that* particular method to see if it throws the exception on bogus input.

```
@Test (expected = A8InvalidInputException.class)
public void testIsValidCharacterWithInvalidCharacter() {
    // write your test here.
}
```

Next, you can change your method to only care about the happy-path of the `isValidCharacter` method, since if you don't return the boolean, you've thrown the exception.

Lastly, you would only concern the tests for `guessCharacter` around whether or not it throws `A8AlreadyGuessedException`.

```
@Test (expected = A8AlreadyGuessedException.class)
public void testGuessCharacterWithAlreadyGuessedValue() {
    // write your test here.
}
```

Comment: Makoto, thanks, but I cannot change the source code.  My instructor provided it.  I, too, would've written separate methods here (maybe testing validity before even passing it as an argument?) as I thought a method is only supposed to do one thing, but hey, I'm the student.  What do I know?

Comment: Well, methods can do many things, but when you're testing, you're only supposed to be testing one thing.  I'm still strongly of the opinion that `isValidCharacter` should be throwing the exception, since it's the only portion of the code that's responsible for asserting invalid input.  Again, it's about limiting the amount of surface area you have to hit with a test - it makes the test writing effort easier, and produces less fragile tests.